# Can old kernel run well on 14.04.5?

Tags: kernel

I had updated from 14.04.1 via Software Updater. And now it's just turned into 14.04.5. However the kernel is still 3.13, not 4.4. What effects/impacts will it give to my laptop if I keep using that old kernel? Can that old kernel handle the new release? Or is updgrading the kernel more recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3.13. kernel will be supported for Ubuntu 14.04 till the release EOL, it will get security and bug fixing updates.

New kernels are needed to support new hardware.

If everything works, there is no need to upgrade the kernel.